# Join dataframe with Aggregrate record s without reducing dimension of dataframe - for pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by, partitioning

I am trying to use the aggregate function in pyspark where I want the dimension of the output data frame to remain unchanged, and query the result with other dataframe.

Says, the result of the aggregrated dataframe:

```
+-----+------------+----------------+
|rowno|date        |prev_date       |
+-----+------------+----------------+
|    3|  2023-08-03|      2023-08-02|
|    4|  2023-08-04|      2023-08-03|
|    5|  2023-08-07|      2023-08-04|
|    6|  2023-08-08|      2023-08-07|
|    8|  2023-08-10|      2023-08-09|
+-----+------------+----------------+
```

Then the logic is:

```
WITH stk AS (
SELECT  distinct 1 as code 
FROM    tableA
WHERE   code in (SELECT distinct code
                         FROM   (SELECT 1 code
                                 FROM   tableA 
                                 WHERE  DATE = prev_date 
                                 EXCEPT
                                 SELECT 1 as stock_code
                                 FROM   tableA
                                 WHERE  DATE = @date 
                                ) A
                        )
        and DATE >= dateprev
```

How do I use spark to reflect the above function, where the date and prev_date is from t he aggregrated tbl.

the approach I tried it to using the row number as below,

```
rowcnt_rowmax = delisted_stocks_df.select(F.min("rowno").alias("rowcnt"), F.max("rowno").alias("rowmax")).first()
rowcnt, rowmax = rowcnt_rowmax["rowcnt"], rowcnt_rowmax["rowmax"]

while rowcnt is not None and rowcnt <= rowmax:
    dateprev_datecurr = delisted_stocks_df.filter(F.col("rowno") == rowcnt).select("prev_date", "date").first()
    dateprev, datecurr = dateprev_datecurr["prev_date"], dateprev_datecurr["date"]

# SQL logic to calculate delisting date
stk = (df.filter((F.col("date") >= dateprev) & ~F.col("stock_code").isin(
    df.filter((F.col("date") == dateprev)).select(stock_code_col)
))
    .select(stock_code_col)
    .distinct()
)
```

However, it returns error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'` and the result is TOO SLOW.

My question is, is there any way to perform those logic other than row no. because row no is not too convenient, probably using the window partitioning is better.